# How to create an image?

Tags: c++, image

In C++ how to create an image, without any library, with cross platform support?

The reason I am bothering doing this without any library is because I need speed. I want to have an array of 3 byte integers and edit the data pixel pixel.

In C++ is there an image data type? If not, how can I simulate one?

**To be clear:** I want to process the data without using any library. The saving to PNG will be done using a library.

Comment: Thanks, I know this library, but I need to do this without any library.

Comment: _"without any library is because I need speed"_ How confident are you that what you write will perform better than something that's been worked on over the course of several years?

Comment: @Michael OpenCV is a) more complex than I need it to be and b) why use OpenCV when I have simple needs?

Comment: The requirement that you don't want to use any library is the deal-breaker here. Some image formats are relative easy to read/write, but once you get to more complicated formats (like for example JPEG) you really need a library. Fortunately for you, most image-handling libraries can be used on multiple platforms.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I only need PNG.

Comment: Ah, so you want to implement the compression yourself too?

Comment: And you *have* read about [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) and the standards that define the file formats?

Comment: I don't believe I can beat what exists out there. There are some cool libraries in c++ doing this. Those libraries (especially the lossy PNG ones) will be able to do the job better than OpenCV (i guess).

Comment: @Luka: I was referring to any library that's been around for a long time, not OpenCV specifically.

Comment: "lossy PNG"? You do know that PNG is specified to be lossless?

Comment: Thanks. My life is not long enough to read those papers, luckily some cool guys did this! :D

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: I know this very well but you can reduce the filesize by reducing the number of non visible colors. This is lossy of some kind.

Comment: see here: http://pngquant.org/

Comment: I recommend "STB image" for png compression, single file, easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ or the STL do not have a standard concept for images. For a basic representation you could use something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>


struct Color {
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
};


class Image {
public:
    const int width;
    const int height;
    Color * const data;

    Image( int width, int height ) : width( width ), height( height ), data( (Color*) malloc( sizeof( Color) * width * height ) )
    {
        memset( (void*) data, 0, sizeof( Color) * width * height );
    }

    ~Image() {
        free( (void*) data );
    }

    void setpixel( int x, int y, Color c ) {
        data[ x + y * width ] = c;
    }

    Color getpixel( int x, int y ) const {
        return data[ x + y * width ];
    }
};



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Image img( 320, 200 );
    img.setpixel( 10, 10, { 50, 255, 0 } );

    Color c = img.getpixel( 10, 10 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what would make access to single pixels very ineffective. since on every [gs]etPixel the index calculation is done.

Comment: No big deal, easily adjusted, he gave me the basic idea

Comment: @vlad_tepesch I don't see a way to make random access to pixels any faster (for arbitrarily sized images).

Comment: single pixel access could not be faster. but image processing algorithms usually walk through the image rowwise. you could return the pointer to the pixel, so that the user can get the start of a line and directly increment the pointer to get the next pixel.